# Multiple Bash Terminals handle single JVM instance

Tags: java, bash, jar, terminal, jvm

I have a Java program which takes two numbers as user input and prints the sum.

If no input is entered after 30 seconds, the program terminates.

The Java code is as follows:

```
public class task {

static double i1;
static double i2;
static boolean breakOut = false;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    int x = 30; // time to wait, in seconds

    while(true) {
        boolean goodInput1 = false;
        while(!goodInput1) {
            BufferedReader in1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            Date date = new Date();
            SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat ("hh:mm:ss");
            System.out.print("Current time: " + ft.format(date));
            System.out.print(" Please enter the first number: ");
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                while ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) < x * 1000 && !in1.ready()) {}

            try {
                if (in1.ready()) {
                    i1 = Double.parseDouble(in1.readLine());
                    goodInput1 = true;
                } else {
                    date = new Date();
                    System.out.print("\nTime now is:  " + ft.format(date));
                    System.out.println(" You have not entered any number so exiting the program.");
                    breakOut = true;
                    break;
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("You have entered bad data, please try again.");
                continue;
            }
        }
        if(breakOut) { break; }

        boolean goodInput2 = false;         
        while(!goodInput2) {
            BufferedReader in2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            Date date = new Date();
            SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat ("hh:mm:ss");                
            System.out.print("Current time: " + ft.format(date));
            System.out.print(" Please enter the second number: ");
            long startTime2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                while ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime2) < x * 1000 && !in2.ready()) {}
            try {
                if (in2.ready()) {
                    i2 = Double.parseDouble(in2.readLine());
                    goodInput2 = true;
                } else {
                    date = new Date();
                    System.out.print("\nTime now is:  " + ft.format(date));
                    System.out.println(" You have not entered any number, exiting the program.");
                    breakOut = true;
                    break;
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("You have entered bad data, please try again.");
                continue;
            }
        }
        if(breakOut) { break; }

    double sum = i1 + i2;
    System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);

    }

    System.out.println("Program Terminated.");

}
```

}

I have the program saved as a Jar executable.

I wrote a script which checks if my Jar process is currently running and starts the process if it is not:

[My Bash Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcrrG.png)

This script ensures that only one JVM instance running my program exists no matter how many different Bash terminals I try to run my Jar from. (Assuming I only use my script to run the process)

The end goal is to allow any terminal connected to a Single JVM, be able to reset the 30 second timer through entering input.

I would like to alter the script to fulfill this functionality. (not to mention changes to the Java code)

My question is:

**Given that a JVM was launched from one Bash terminal, How could I allow another terminal to gain a handle on that particular JVM instance?**

Comment: java.net.ServerSocket/Socket

Comment: On a Unix box, you can probably get the JVM to open other terminals directly as `/dev/[pt]tyXX` but you still need to tell your JVM about the terminals it should access, for which you need to user ServerSocket/Socket or more advanced forms of inter-process communication.

Answer (score 1):

From an operating system perspective, bash terminal is a process, just as the jvm process, what you try to do is interprocess communication.

So you have to modify the java code to support interprocess function ,such as socket or signal.

Terminal bash process cannot get another process's  ability.

Comment: But interprocess functionality requires having several JVM's interacting with each other right?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using ServerSocket/Socket for the solution. I had one Jar for the server and one Jar for the client(s). The first terminal would run the Server Jar and the following terminals would run a Client Jar.

The Single JVM part of the requirements was what confused me the most, but in the end, a client-server solution was the way to go about getting the desired functionality.